# Posting updates on Facebook and twitter from background services (or Broadcast receiver)

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, twitter

**I want to post updates on Facebook and Twitter when my application is running in background.**

*I want a functionality in which at a given particular time I need to post updates (no matters my application is on foreground or background).*

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Subclass `Service` and post the updates from there. See here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html

Comment: Can you please explain a bit details.